# shell script pass argument with space

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, space

I have the following script (example):

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts a: opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        a) val="$OPTARG";;
        ?) echo "use the flag \"-a\""
           exit 2;;
    esac
done
echo "a specified with: ${val}"
```

When I now call this script with `test.sh -a "here is a string"` the output is: `a specified with: here` but **not** as I would like to have `a specified with: here is a string`.

I know that I can call the script with `test.sh -a here\ is\ a\ string` or `test.sh -a "here\ is\ a\ string"` and it will work. But in my case I can not manipulate the string I want to pass.
So how can I change my `getopts` function to make it work?

I also tried `getopt`, but I worked even more wors:

```
commandsShort="a:"
commandsLong="aval:"
TEMP=`getopt \
        -o $commandsShort \
        -l $commandsLong \
        -q \
        -n "$0" -- "$@"`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The output you're claiming to have is not what I get; for me, the output is what you would like to get. Exactly how are you invoking test.sh? Not directly from the shell I presume? I suspect that you may be calling it in some way that strips the quotes.

Comment: @ghoti I am so sorry ... the problem indeed is by passing the command thru an other script that has the content `eval "test.sh $@"`. How can I pass all parameters to `test.sh` in a correct way so that the result is the same like calling `test.sh` directly? (`$*` will also not work ...)

Comment: @christopher2007 Why are you using eval ?

Comment: @123 good question^^ I changed it to the normal invoce `test.sh "$@"` and now it is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This got solved in comments on your question.  :-)

You're calling the script with:

```
eval "test.sh $@"
```

The effect of this "eval" line, if "here is a string" is your option, is to create the command line that is in the quotes:

```
test.sh here is a string
```

and **eval**uate it.

Per the additional comments, if you can avoid eval, you should.

That said, if you need it, you could always quote the string within the eval:

```
eval "test.sh \"$@\""
```

Or if you don't like escaping quotes, use singles, since your `$@` will be expanded due to the outer quotes being double:

```
eval "test.sh '$@'"
```

And finally, as you mentioned in comments, just running directly may be the best option:

```
test.sh "$@"
```

**Note** that if your `$@` includes the `-a` option, you may have a new problem. Consider the command line:

```
test.sh "-a here is a string"
```

In this case, your entire string, starting with `-a`, is found in `$1`, and you will have no options for getopts and no OPTARG.